# Leaflet drop markers animation

Tags: leaflet, markers, animation

Is it possible to do drop markers on the map like in google maps (https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) in leaflet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no! It is referred to as Marker Bounce Effect. This is in the [wish-list](http://leaflet.uservoice.com/forums/150880-ideas-and-suggestions-for-leaflet/suggestions/3078585-marker-bounce-animation) for  Leaflet but not implemented yet.

If you up-vote it there, perhaps we can see this feature soon, or if you are really up for it, you could build your own bouncy marker as a [3rd party plugin](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/plugins.html). Such plugins can be created by extending the core Leaflet.js. Refer to one such example [MarkerCluster](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.markercluster) in github.

Answer (score 6):

Can drop marker like google maps using this Third party plugin
[bouncemarker](https://github.com/maximeh/leaflet.bouncemarker)

And here is a demo [Demo](http://maximeh.github.io/leaflet.bouncemarker/)